# Swift 2 migration Linker command failed

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, xcode7

I just update xcode to version 7 and migrating my code to swift 2. I'm now unable to compile my app because of the error described below :

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "protocol witness table for C.NSFetchedResultsChangeType : Swift.Hashable in CoreData", referenced from
>   type metadata accessor for [C.NSFetchedResultsChangeType : ObjectiveC.NSArray]

Does anybody have an idea about the way to solve it ?